# Is it possible to do something like `:normal :` to enter command line during the execution of a vimscript function?

Tags: vim

I am writing a vim script function. During its execution, I want to enter the command line to provide some arguments that cannot be decided in advance, for some specific commands. I want  something like

```
:startinsert
```

But should goes like

```
:startcmd
```

Is it possible? Or some other ways around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around, we can use following code to mimic the command line.

```
exec input(prompt, text, completion)
```

`text` and `completion` are optional, `:h input()` for more

But one thing to note:

the built-in completions of vim (`:h command-completion` for more) indicated by the `completion` argument complete with entire preceding line before the cursor when you hit `<tab>` in `input()`. This may be not what you want, e.g., I just want to complete the last word instead of the entire preceding line.

To solve this problem, you have to write your own completion function, please refer to `:h command-completion-custom` and `:h command-completion-customlist`

Comment: `:call` (or rather `:let value =`, since you want to store the user entry), not `:execute` (which is for Ex commands, not Vim functions).

Answer (score 1):

`input()` is what you want.

Here is an example:

```
let myFile = input("Choose a file: ", "", "file")
execute 'edit ' . myFile
```

and another one:

```
buffer `=input("Choose a buffer: ", "", "buffer")`
```

See `:help input()`.

---

You can also allow your user to choose from a predefined set of options with `inputlist()`.